# maven project setup configuration in eclipse

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am new to maven. I tried to setup my first maven project in eclipse IDE, but while creating the project I am getting an error:

Errors occurred during the build.

```
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'SpringLoginApplication'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

I am unable to find the reason for this error. Can anybody please help me on this regard?

Comment: I am able to solve the above problem by executing the following code in command-prompt                                                                                                cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i

Comment: Does the maven project compiles on command line `mvn clean compile`?